# Property '_elementRef' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<any>'

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, viewchild

I am trying to move a button along with a sidebar as it is opened. I am using ElementRef to grab the component and manipulate it manually with Typescipt. However, although I see _elementRef is part of the element when I log it, I get the error ***Property '_elementRef' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.*** I also thought that this would have been automatic with changing the, but it did not seem to work.

**TS**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('toggle', {static: false}) toggle: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  toggleButton() {
    console.log(this.toggle);
    this.toggle._elementRef.nativeElement.style.marginLeft = "50px";
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container" autosize>

  <mat-drawer #drawer class="example-sidenav" mode="over" opened=false>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/services']">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/contact']">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </mat-drawer>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="drawer.toggle(); toggleButton()" id="toggleButton" #toggle>
        <p class="menu"></p>
      </button>
</mat-drawer-container>
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**css**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #toggleButton{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 500;
    margin-left: 40vw;
  }
  .menu{
    margin-top: 50%;
    height: 4vh;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64' aria-labelledby='title' aria-describedby='desc' role='img' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Ctitle%3EMenu%3C/title%3E%3Cdesc%3EA line styled icon from Orion Icon Library.%3C/desc%3E%3Cpath data-name='layer2' fill='none' stroke='%23202020' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M2 8h60v8H2zm0 20h60v8H2z' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-linecap='round'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath data-name='layer1' fill='none' stroke='%23202020' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M2 48h60v8H2z' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-linecap='round'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

mat-drawer{
  position: fixed;
}

  nav{
    width: 40vw;
  }

  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  nav ul li{
    font-size: 3vh;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav ul li a{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .contact-button{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `_elementRef`. you should rather use `nativeElement` directly as below,

```
toggleButton() {
    console.log(this.toggle);
    this.toggle.nativeElement.style.marginLeft = "50px !important";
}
```

Comment: It compiles but the style is not changed

Comment: you can try ` = "50px !important"`.

Comment: still no response

Comment: it applies but since you are using 'angular material', it doesn't overwrite. You can verify it by taking a normal HTML button.

Comment: I am not getting a response from the regular button either

Comment: This is very strange. Its hard to tell you anything further. But, i'm pretty sure about my answer. That is what you want. There should be some minor problem which you need to figure out.

Comment: by the way, try removing `margin-left: 40vw;` from css. That doesn't look OKAY to me.

Comment: I dont get a response while removing it but I do get the error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)`

Comment: I figured it out using style binding

Comment: use ::ng-deep {}